# My java script function to disable the enter key is not working

Tags: javascript, vb.net

When I am calling the java script from my VB code as

```
oCell.InnerHtml += "<input type='submit' id='btnOK' value='" & Phrasebook.Text("Button_OK") & "' onclick='helpCommit();' onkeyup='disableEnterKey(event);'/>"
```

its not working.

My Javascript function is

```
function disableEnterKey(event)
    {
        var key= window.event.keyCode;

        if(key == 13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: my code is  

oCell.InnerHtml += "<input type='submit' id='btnOK' value='" & Phrasebook.Text("Button_OK") & "' onclick='helpCommit();' onkeyup='disableEnterKey(event);'/>"

Comment: Have youlooked at the javascript console for any errors. You use `e` but the parameter is called `event` for starters

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way

```
document.getElementById("btnOK").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
   {
       console.log("Disabled");
       return false;
   }
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0v70gkz/)** suiting your situtation. Check browser console on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>